# I want to conditionally split a List if exxchange is a List and continue processing

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to conditionally split an exchange into its contents if it is a List, otherwise leave it as a single item and have both go to the same processor

I ideally do not want to set up lots of inbetween direct:endpoints to achieve this

```
from( X )
    .when( body().isInstanceOf( List.class )
        .split( body() )
        .setHeader( "x", constant( "I don't care " ) // this needs to be set as split must have at least one child node
        .process( ? ) // here the exchange.in.body is now a single item from the List // this is what I want to continue outside of this when block
    .end() // also tried .end().end() and .endChoice()
    .process( ... ) // here the exchange in is a List again, I want it to be the single items, split
```

I do not understand why the exchange is not left as single units, that is how it becomes a List again when it leaves the when 'block'.
I get the feeling Camel 'expects' me to use direct:endpoints to achieve this, but I find readability decreases quickly the more direct points are used and want to avoid them if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the way camel's split component is setup only the code underneath a list will process as individual records.  Once you close the split block you are back to a single exchange.  The only way to break that up would be to leverage a mid point like a direct endpoint.  If you want to break up the logic you can always create separate route builder classes.  The other option is to request a feature on the forums.

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregation strategy on the splitter to *build* the output you want from the splitter. There you can store the splitted sub message you want, instead of the original message that the splitter uses today.

Comment: Could you clarify this, please. Where would one store the sub-message?