# Inject a splitter that never aggregates

Tags: apache-camel

**Camel ver 2.17.3:**  I want to insert a splitter into a route so that split messages remain split. If I have a "direct" route with a splitter, when control returns from the inner route, I no longer have split messages, only the original.

```
from("direct:in")
.transform(constant("A,B,C"))
.inOut("direct:inner")
.log("RET-VAL: ${in.body}");

from("direct:inner")
.split()
.tokenize(",")      
.log("AFTER-SPLIT ${in.body}")
;
```

Based on [the answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663358/i-want-to-conditionally-split-a-list-if-exxchange-is-a-list-and-continue-process), and Claus's comment below, I tried inserting my own aggregator and always marking the group "COMPLETE". Only the last (split) message is being returned to the outer route.

```
from("direct:in")
.transform(constant("A,B,C"))
.inOut("direct:inner")
.log("RET-VAL: ${in.body}");

from("direct:inner")
.split(body().tokenize(","), new MyAggregationStrategy())
.log("AFTER-SPLIT ${in.body}")
;


public static class MyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy
{
  @Override
  public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    System.out.println("Agg called with:"+newExchange.getIn().getBody());
    newExchange.setProperty(Exchange.AGGREGATION_COMPLETE_CURRENT_GROUP, true);
    return newExchange;
  }
}
```

How do I get the messages to stay split, regardless of how routes are nested etc.?

Comment: You can use an aggregation strategy on the splitter directly, where you can build up what you want as the outgoing response message from the splitter. Then you do not need the aggreagator.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I placed My aggregation strategy on the Splitter, but it only returns the last. I thought setting Exchange.AGGREGATION_COMPLETE_CURRENT_GROUP to true would make it return each split message separately, but it only returns "C", (from the original "A, B, C")
Is there some other way to make the Aggregator simply send out each split message separately, as-is?

Comment: Study the Camel documentation about splitter and aggregator some more and how it works

Comment: The request/reply sample in the Splitter documentation shows an aggregator that combines everything. Looking at the Aggregator documentation, it seemed that setting  Exchange.AGGREGATION_COMPLETE_CURRENT_GROUP to true each time the aggregate() was called would "flush" the individual message out.
But, obviously, some concept is eluding me here!

Answer (score 1):

See this EIP
http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html

with the *splitter only* example.

And in the `AggregationStrategy` you combine together all those splitted sub-messages into one message which is the result you want, eg the outgoing message of the splitter when its done. How you do that depends on your messages and what you want to keep. For example you can put together the sub messages in a `List` or maybe its XML based and you can append the XML fragments, or something.

Comment: I don't want to combine the messages. I want to split them and let them remain split when the split ends. Maybe that is my main misunderstanding? Maybe the split()...end() acts like a parenthesis and the return will always be a single Exchange *outside* that? The Splitter documentation on "What the Splitter returns" says one can change the default. I understand how to change what is returned on that *single* message. I thought there may be a way to return multiple Exchanges to the caller, but perhaps I've got that wrong.

Comment: Yes its like end parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That is useful in pushing some of my design in one direction rather than another.