# How to prevent Camel splitter from aggregating after processing?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a camel route set up in the following way:

```
List<SomeRouteInfo> routes = getRouteInfo(); //I crete the routes using the info in the list.
for ( SomeRouteInfo info : routes ){
    RouteDefinition routeDef = from(info.from());

    routeDef
        .errorHandler(someErrorHandler);
        .routeId(info.getId());

    if (info.someCondition()){
        routeDef
            .split().method(someSplitterBean)
            .process(processorBean1) //The message seems split here.
    }

    routeDef
        .process(processorBean2) //The message is no longer split here. I need it to be.
        .to(info.to())
}
```

Basically, some routes I want the splitter to be present on, on others I dont. The info for whether or not to split a message is not present in the message itself.

So, the problem is when I process in processorBean1 it seems like I have multiple messages. Unfortunately it seems like at processorBean2 I don't have the same. Instead I have the original message body back.

I wan't the split up messages to fail individually in processorBean2 on exception without knocking down everthing else. So, I want it to be seperate messages at processorBean2 for that reason. What can I do to accoplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the **[Splitter EIP](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/split-eip.html) returns by default the original message**. This is explained at "[What the Splitter retuns](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/split-eip.html#_what_the_splitter_returns)" in the Camel docs.

I assume that the **Splitter is implicitly "closed"** at the end of the `routeDef` configuration in the `if` block.

Therefore, your route effectively looks like this:

```
...
.routeId()
.split().method(someSplitterBean)
    .process(processorBean1) // here you got splitted messages
.end // end splitter; from here you got the original message (before split)
.process(processorBean2) 
.to(info.to())
```

So, for your case you have mutliple possibilities:

1: Move `processorBean2` and `.to(info.to())` **inside the Splitter**. I.e. directly below `processorBean1`. That way the splitter still returns the original message, but you don't use it anymore.

```
.split().method(someSplitterBean)
    .process(processorBean1) // here you got splitted messages
    .process(processorBean2) 
    .to(info.to())
.end // end splitter; from here you got the original message (before split)
```

In your case you would need to make, starting from the splitter, the whole rest of the route conditional.

2: You **add your own aggregator strategy** to return for example a collection that contains the splitted messages instead of the original. However, **the splitter can only return one single message.** So [you can't continue with the individual splitted messages after the splitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786820/inject-a-splitter-that-never-aggregates). The only place where you get them is **inside** the splitter.

```
.split(method(someSplitterBean), new MyStrategy())
...
```

3: You **divide** the "split path" and the "non-split path" (condition in your route builder) **in two separate sub-routes** and just make the `.to([subroute]) conditional.

```
routeDef
    .errorHandler(someErrorHandler);
    .routeId(info.getId());

if (info.someCondition()){
    routeDef.to("direct:mySplitRoute")
} else {
    routeDef.to("direct:myStandardRoute")
}
```

This way you got a bit of redundancy in the two routes but on the other hand you got a cleanly separated processing of the (obviously) different message types.

Comment: I have tried writing an aggrgator. But the aggrigator creates a block of itself where it's effective. Just like the splitter. Do you know how to write an aggregator that won't do that?

Comment: I edited my answer. You can't get the splitted messages after the splitter. However, you can return a collection of messages or something else that is more useful than the original message.

Comment: Ended up sending the message to a seda queue from inside the splitter block.